# Multi-parameters Optimization in R

Tags: r, parameters, mathematical-optimization

I want to change the value of parameters within upper and lower limits for calibration of the hydrological model by objective function (NSE or model efficiency).
How can I optimize the value of the multiple parameters within upper and lower limits? I used `optimx` and it shows error.
I need to estimate 11 parameters of the model in the `calibfun`.

```
optimx (Par=c(1,0.85,1,500,0,500,0,0,3,35,0), calibfun, 
        lower=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
        upper=c(1,1,200,5000,100,5000,100,100,100,100,100),
        method="L-BFGS-B")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error does it show? You also need to provide a reproducible example – that means code and data that can be used to replicate your problem. (PS [`topmodel`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/topmodel/index.html) provides a function for calculating Nash-Sutcliffe efficiency.)

Comment: FYI, [PA-DDS](http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/~asadzadm/software.html) is very good for multi-objective optimization especially expensive problems. It won the 1st place at [Black Box Optimization Competition](https://bbcomp.ini.rub.de/results/BBComp2016-2OBJ-expensive/summary.html)

Comment: Another good one is [SMS-EGO](https://bbcomp.ini.rub.de/results/BBComp2017EMO/summary.html) which is available in [mlrMBO](https://github.com/mlr-org/mlrMBO) package. HTH

Comment: A parallel version of PA-DDS is available in [OSTRICH - Optimization Software Toolkit](http://www.eng.buffalo.edu/~lsmatott/Ostrich/OstrichMain.html)

Comment: The error is here
 Error in optimx.check(par, optcfg$ufn, optcfg$ugr, optcfg$uhess, lower,  : 
  Cannot evaluate function at initial parameters